# Why does main(int argc, char** argv) allow to override 'argv' parameters? Why and how does this work?

Tags: c++

I found that main() allows overriding the argv[] parameters, because they are not *const*.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%i %s\n", argc, argv[1]);
    argv[1][0] = 'X';
    argv[1][4] = 'X';
    printf("%i %s\n", argc, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

And below is the result. It compiled and worked.

[image]

At first, I expected some program crush like undefined behaviour. However, it may make sense that I may want to have a program that accept sensitive data as parameter, but after I use it, I would like to override it it immediately. Is this is the only reason or there are others?

I would like to understand how this is working. I.e, where is the char** argv[] strings array located? How is it created and deleted? Etc.

Comment: `const` or not in the declared signature, what you're doing is undefined behavior. Stop.

Comment: The strings passed to your program are stored in locations by the Operating System; this is not a C++ thing.  Before your program starts, the OS passes the quantity and location of the parameters passed to your program.  The array of strings *should be* passed as a pointer to constant data, since many operating systems don't like your program parameters to be modified.  Modifying your program's parameters is undefined behavior.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ you mean in the tile of the page? it was a typo - fixed.

Comment: The signature of `main` was strongly influenced by **C++**’s **C** heritage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux/x86-64, the `argc`, `argv`, and `env` parameters are stored on the call stack by the kernel doing the [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) according to [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) conventions.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54957101/841108) and the [Linux Assembly HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/).